# How to find minimum number of trips to do in order to complete this work from point A to point B using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, logical-reads

So I am solving this problem given as:

There are bags carrying weights from 1 to 3 units and I have to carry them from point A to point B.
Weights are given of bags in array. All weights are less than 3 unit.

```
weights = [1, 1.78, 2.2, 2.73, 3]
```

So I have to make the trips carrying the bags should not cross the total weight greater than 3 unit. In order to that I have to make minimum number of trips.

**Example:**
weights = [1.01, 1.99, 2.5, 1.5, 1.01]

I can carry all bags in 3 trips minimum as:

[1.01 + 1.99, 2.5, 1.5 + 1.01].

Means how to determine the minimum no. of trips to carry the weight bags from point A to point B?

What logic can be applied?

Comment: Sorry, the point of Stackoverflow is not to write your code for you. You need to try something, show your attempts and your efforts, and if you're stuck somewhere in particular, we can then help you to make your code work. But you can't just come here and say "Here's a problem, please write the solution."

Comment: yes I have tried.
I will post my answer.

Comment: Please read about "Knapsack problem"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#:~:text=The%20knapsack%20problem%20is%20a,is%20as%20large%20as%20possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to loop through a sorted list and always pick out the biggest number first.

Then you loop through the remaining elements and combine it with the largest number, where the combined sum is less than your target.

Since the largest number should always be the hardest to "pair", this should give you the optimal number of trips.

However this approach doesn't distribute weight evenly. It will favor packing pairs as big as possible.

Here is a simple implementation:

```js
function SplitToBalancedPairs(inputs, target) {
    let outputs = [];
    inputs = inputs.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a - b);
    while (inputs.length > 0) {
        let a = inputs.pop();
        let b;
        let c;
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            b = inputs[i];
            if (a + b <= target) {
                c = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (c !== void 0) {
            outputs.push([a, inputs.splice(c, 1).pop()]);
        }
        else {
            outputs.push([a]);
        }
    }
    return outputs;
}
//Test
let weights = [1, 1.78, 2.2, 2.73, 3];
let results = SplitToBalancedPairs(weights, 3);
console.log(results);
console.log(results.map(a => a.reduce((b, c) => b + c)));
```

Comment: But ow many trips? How to count them? I am not asking the combinatioms??

Comment: @Biku7 The length of the resulting list of pairs would be your number of trips. For the list in the example above it would be 4 trips.

Answer (score 0):

I've used greedy approach here, which is to sort the weights array, and combine the heaviest one with lightest and lighter ones until we reach the limit. Python code:

```py
def solve(A):
    A.sort()  
    n = len(A)
    i =0
    j = n-1
    ans=0
    while i<=j: 
        while A[i]+A[j] <=3: 
            i+=1
        ans+=1
        j-=1
  
    return ans 

print(solve([1.01, 1.99, 2.5, 1.5, 1.01]))
```

Time Complexity: O(n)

Comment: But this is not Javascript

Comment: yeah but logic has also been asked, so i thought it could be of some help :)